# Sonarqube cpd exclusion not honored

Tags: java, sonarqube

I want to exclude all files which end in DTO.java from sonarqube code duplication checks. I did this with:

```
sonar.cpd.exclusions=**/*DTO.java
```

Also when I look into the background tasks and the scanner context, I can see that the parameter is correctly set:

```
  - sonar.cpd.exclusions=**/*DTO.java
```

Although all this settings I get a "1 duplicated blocks of code must be removed."(common-java:DuplicatedBlocks) in my ImportantDTO.java

I also excluded these files from coverage, with the same expression and this works fine:

```
sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/*DTO.java,...
```

Sonarqube-Version: Version 6.7.5 (build 38563)
Sonar-Scanner: Gradle Plugin org.sonarqube 2.6.2

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Those exclusions apply to the metrics, but not to the rules. Try a [multi-criteria Issue Exclusion](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#header-10) instead.

Comment: Mh if I insert the expression **/*DTO.java on the website under Administration - General Settings - Analysis Scope - Duplication Exclusions the issues are gone. But shouldn't it also work if I specify it in my build.gradle?

Comment: Exclusions are multi-value parameters and as such are extremely difficult to specify properly outside the UI

Comment: 404 on this link today

Comment: Thanks @Vipin. The docs got moved and then the redirects dropped. :-(
Fixed

Comment: Hello @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam, through UI on section "Ignore issues on Multiple Criteria" I added Rule Key Pattern common-java:DuplicatedBlocks and File Path Pattern .*\.dto\..*.java , after this executed sonar analysis as well but it does not ignore duplicate rule on DTO classes.

Comment: @Vipin I would need more about your context, & comments on an answer is not the appropriate place

Comment: My bad @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam, please ignore question in comment. Asked question here https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-do-we-ignore-duplicated-lines-issues-for-particular-files/73308